# retrieve p7m file from db2 blob field

Tags: java, pdf, servlets

I need to retrieve a p7m pdf file stored in blob field and put it for direct download by pointing a specific url.

Now I'm using the following code for retrieve and publish pdf, but opening the file saved with a tool for view digital signature the signature is not valid and the pdf seems like corrupted.

```
public byte[] getPdfOrdini(String xxx, String tipo) throws Exception, SQLException {
    Blob pdf;
    byte[] pdfData = null;
    Connection conn = new test().getConnectionOrdini();
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    // Query
    if(tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("pnf"))
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("Select ... From .. Where ..");
    if(tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("pf"))
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("Select ... From .. Where .. = ?");
    pstmt.setString(1, xxx);
    ResultSet rset = pstmt.executeQuery();

    if(tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("pnf")){

        while (rset.next()) {
            pdf = rset.getBlob(1);
            pdfData = pdf.getBytes(1, (int) pdf.length());
        }

        //System.out.println("dimensione blob --> " + pdfData.length);
    }else{
        while (rset.next()) {
            pdf = rset.getBlob(1);
            pdfData = pdf.getBytes(1, (int) pdf.length());
        }
    }
    rset.close();
    pstmt.close();

    return pdfData;
}
```

and this code for publish pdf for download:

```
<jsp:useBean id="PDF" class="pdf.test" scope="session" />
<%
Connection conn = null;

if ( request.getParameter("protocollo") != null )
{

String protocollo = request.getParameter("xxx") ;
String tipo = request.getParameter("type");   

try
{  
   String downloadFileName = "O" + xxx + ".pdf.p7m";
   conn = new pdf.test().getConnection();
   conn.setAutoCommit (false);  

   // get the image from the database
   byte[] pdfData = PDF.getPdfOrdini(xxx, tipo);   
   // display the image

   File pdf = new File(downloadFileName);
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pdf);
   fos.write(pdfData);
   fos.flush();
   fos.close();

   response.setContentType( "application/x-download" );
   response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + downloadFileName );
   conn.close();
}
catch (IllegalStateException il){
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
  throw e;
}
finally
{

}  
}
%>
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two while blocks for reading are the same, but it should work anyhow.
You may try this, worked always for me on DB2:

```
byte[] pdfData = null;
ResultSet rset = pstmt.executeQuery();
if (rset.next())
{
  pdfData = rset.getBytes(1);
}
conn.close();
return pdfData;
```

Added:
Next Thing is, I do not see you writing the data to the browser in your JSP.
Something like this:

```
byte[] pdfData = PDF.getPdfOrdini(xxx, tipo);
char[] data = new char[pdfData.length];
for (int i = 0; i < pdfData.length; i++) {
    data[i] = (char) pdfData[i];
    }
response.setContentType( "application/x-download" );
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + downloadFileName );
response.setHeader("Content-length", Integer.toString(data.length));
out.write( data, 0, data.length);
out.flush();
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I still get the same result. 
I think it's a problem of file generation in jsp but I can not understand where is the problem

Comment: Are you sure that the data is correctly stored in the database?

Comment: Yes, in my webapp I also provide a jsp for show the pdf file in visualization mode via browser and the pdf is opened correctly. The problem is generate a file downloadable for check digital signature info.

Comment: See my edited answer: Are you writing the data to the browser?

Comment: Sorry for the quetion, but the write method of out object wants char array for first param but I have byte array.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved!
Before your last reply I tried to use the OutputStream of Response to write data of pdf file and it works fine.